# call method Index() using index() or iNdEx()

Tags: php, oop

how can I call a method from another class and not be restriced to case sensitivity?

```
class TestA
{
    function Index()
    {}
}

class TestB extends TestA
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function load()
    {
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

Assume all the logic is correct when extending another class, how can i do something like that?

I thought of using a `preg_math()` type of approach, but I'm not 100% sure of the logic behind that.

Perhaps use the `__call()` magic method?

Comment: @SLaks - Because I want to parse my URI in my MVC to call methods and whatnot, a user could use Index as a method but call if using /index rather than /Index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP methods aren't case-sensitive in the first place. [See?](http://codepad.org/bRaGPw8I)

Comment: whaaaaaa? are you serious?? hmmm, thats extremely good information to have =) thank you!

Comment: @Eli: No problem. (No problem indeed!)